# MySql databases are deleted after upgrading mac os to Mojave

Tags: mysql, database, macos-high-sierra, macos-mojave

I had mysql installed on my mac os high sierra and it had some databases created on it. When i upgraded my operating system to mac os Mojave and connected phpmyadmin to mysql i've found that my databases are not there anymore. 
Is there a way to retrieve the databases i had?

Comment: Unless you kept the database data in a system directory, I don't know why an OS upgrade would have removed it. Anyway, get it back using Time Machine.

Comment: Maybe your MySQL configuration is pointing to a different directory, and you just need to fix that?

Comment: This question should probably be on [dba.se] or [apple.se]. It's not a programming question.